# PHP based thrift API client like thirft.apache.org example client in python

Tags: php, python, thrift, thrift-protocol

I want to write PHP based thrift API client like thirft.apache.org example client in python  at: http://thrift.apache.org/

I write this code:

```
      //A struture
      $up = UserProfile($uid=1,
             $name="Mark Slee",
             $blurb="I'll find something to put here.");

      # Talk to a server via TCP sockets, using a binary protocol
      $fp = fsockopen("localhost",9090, $errno, $errstr, 90);
      # Use the service we already defined
      $service=fwrite($fp, $up);

      while (!feof($fp)) {
          echo fgets($fp, 128);
      }
```

so is it correct alternative of python client code at : http://thrift.apache.org/

Please give any suggestion as I am new to it.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the [Thrift Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/) at the [Thrift Usage](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsage) page. That has examples in many supported languages, in particular, there's an [example client in PHP](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsagePhp).

Comment: I have seen this at many places but don't know that from where can I get thses files: `$GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] = 'thrift';

require_once 'thrift/Thrift.php';
require_once 'thrift/transport/TTransport.php';
require_once 'thrift/transport/TSocket.php';
require_once 'thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.php';
require_once 'thrift/transport/TFramedTransport.php';
require_once 'thrift/transport/TBufferedTransport.php';
`
Where will these files? Will I download it from some where or I will need to install some thing for it?

Comment: They're part of the download package for Thrift available here: http://thrift.apache.org/download/ Download and extract the contents of the tar file and look in the `lib/php/src` directory.

Comment: In windows , after installing will it go to windows directory?

Comment: do you know that where will it be installed if I will use .exe files under windows. because I think tar file is for linux?

Comment: The .exe file for windows is only the thrift *compiler*. In addition to that, you need the support files provided in the .tar file.

Comment: ok so these are just simple files that I will place on my server on linux or windows and will just include them, while .exe file is compiler that will be required for writing thrift server not client?

Comment: I got from it what I  asked that's why I am marking it right answer however I am still confuse about the `service` file but I think this is a different question, thanks Pablo